# Unable to bootstrap ClojureScript

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I got the latest version from Github and followed the instructions:

> $ script/bootstrap
>   Fetching Clojure...
>   Copying clojure-1.3.0/clojure-1.3.0.jar to lib/clojure.jar...
>   Cleaning up Clojure directory...
>   Cleaning up Clojure archive...
>   Fetching Google Closure library...
>   [closure-library-20110323-r790.zip]
>     End-of-central-directory signature not found.
>   Either this file is not a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.
>   In the
>     latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
>     the last disk(s) of this archive.
>
> unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of closure-library-20110323-r790.zip or
>           closure-library-20110323-r790.zip.zip, and cannot find closure-library-20110323-r790.zip.ZIP, period.

I'm on Mac OSX Lion

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this on both Mac OS X Lion and Ubuntu 11.04 and it worked just fine. Maybe you got a bad download during the bootstrap? Delete your ClojureScript folder, git clone it from github again and try the bootstrap again.